# Horizontal Slide Expandable Listview

Tags: android, listview, slider, expandablelistview, horizontal-scrolling

I've searched for libraries, but i have found that existing libraries only support vertical slider. Anyone know any library capable of handle things such as “automatic collapse item when another is clicked”, and so on.

I'm not asking for a piece of code that ilustrate how to do it. Instead, i'm looking for something more robust and tested, like this library https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView, but it must support horizontal slider.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [library](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview) is just what I needed it